# Is there a vertical blur in WPF? (For a Zune-like vu meter)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, effects

I'm trying to make a vu meter like the Zune desktop:

[image]

Mine is on top, the original is the bottom one. I know the colors are different but, I think the problem is that the Zune one is using vertical blur and I'm using vertical+horizontal.

Mine vu bars are made like this:

```
    void CreateNewVUBar(int left) {
        var obj = new Rectangle();
        obj.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.OrangeRed);
        obj.Width = 70;
        obj.Height = 100;
        obj.SetValue(HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

        var effect = new BlurEffect();
        effect.Radius = 30;
        effect.RenderingBias = RenderingBias.Quality;

        obj.Effect = effect;

        var tmp = obj.Margin;
        tmp.Left = left;
        obj.Margin = tmp;

        vubargrid.Children.Add(obj);
    }
```

Is there a way in WPF to make only vertical blur?
Or there is something that I'm missing?

*NOTE: I know that Zune doesn't use WPF.*

Answer (score 0):

did you considered LinearGradientBrush  ?
and move the start and end points  - at msdn:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.lineargradientbrush(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: you can mimic this by several GradientStop like the last example at the link